# cbind elements in two lists using mapply

Tags: r

If I have two lists.

```
L1 <- list(a1,a2,a3)

L2 <- list(b1,b2,b3)
```

What's the best way to obtain a new list.

```
L3 <- list(c1,c2,c3)
```

, such that

```
c1 <- cbind(a1,b1)
c2 <- cbind(a2,b2)
etc...
```

Thank you so much,

Answer (score 2):

```
mapply(cbind, L1, L2, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Comment: Or just `Map(cbind, L1, L2)`